# logical vector subsetting in R

Tags: r, vector, logic, subset

I'm writing a function in R and I got stuck in a vector subsetting.

Let's assume I have the following vector:

```
  ratio<-c(0,0,0,0,1.3,1.4)
```

I would like to subset the vector taking all values > 0 and IF one or more 0 are present I want to include in the final vector only one 0.

Expected output:

```
subset<-(0,1.3,1.4)
```

I tried the following:

```
sebset1<-ratio[ratio>0]
subset1
[1] 1.3 1.4
```

Then I used if:

```
subset2<- if(c(ratio==0)) {append (subset1, 0,after=length(subset1))}
```

I get this warning:

```
Warning message:
In if (c(ratio == 0)) { :the condition has length > 1 and   only the first element will be used
```

But it works:

```
subset2
[1] 1.3 1.4 0.0
```

However, this solution does not work for vector that have no 0, for ex.:

```
ratio2<-c(3,4,2,3,4)
```

because when I use

```
if
```

I obtain a NULL vector as

```
subset2
```

Any idea where I can improve my code?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If `0` is the _only_ value that can appear multiple times, then `unique(ratio[ratio >= 0])` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Unfortunately, this is not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.. Its without subset

```
#if ratio's value between 0 to +Inf
mysubset = c(ratio[ratio>0],unique(ratio[ratio==0]))

#if ratio's value between -Inf to +Inf and you want to remove only zero like you mentioned in question 
mysubset = c(ratio[ratio!=0],unique(ratio[ratio==0]))
```

Comment: Just for me to understand, the trick is using `unique`, is that right? The function screen for repeated elements and report and object of the same class just once. Right?

Comment: As long as your vector has positive values and zero it will work.. If you want it for negative just change first condition from ratio>0 to ratio!=0

Answer (score 2):

Structuring the code like this most closely resembles your description of the algorithm in English:

```
filtered.ratio <- ratio[ratio > 0]
if (any(ratio == 0)) {
  filtered.ratio <- c(filtered.ratio, 0)
}
```

Note that `append` is really only preferred over `c` when elements need to be inserted at an internal position in a vector. This rarely happens, so you can safely forget about `append`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did not quite get what you meant concerning `append`. Could you shortly explain it better, or maybe link me some good examples? Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 1):

the `if` command in R is not vectorised, so `if(ratio==0)` only compares the first element to zero, so won't work if the first zero is later in the vector. Try:

```
subset1 <- ratio[ratio>0]
if(any(ratio==0)) subset2 <- c(0,subset1) else subset2 <- subset
```

Note also that if returns `NULL` when the test is `FALSE` and there is no `else` part, that's what's causing your problems with `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you very much this work really well! Basically in with `any` you are looking for the logical condition though all the vector. If the condition is true then `0` and `subset1` are printed. If is not true `subset2=subset1`. Is that right?

Comment: Yes that's right, `any` just condenses down a whole load of `or` statements i.e. `ratio[1]==0 or ratio[2]==0 or ...`